# why does my script fail when it hits the appendChild?

Tags: javascript

When I call my function it fails when it hits the appendChild I have no idea why:

I create my function:

```
Auto.prototype.create = function(container){
   this.contain = container;

   var mask = document.createElement("div");
   mask.style.position = "absolute";

   this.contain.appendChild(mask);
```

When I call the create function, it fails when it hits the appenChild do I need to call that too? because I thought that calling the function was all I needed.

Comment: what value of container have you passed to create method?

Comment: what is the error in your browser console.. that is the value of `container`

Comment: See [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: the error: is Cannot read property of 'appendChild' undefined.

Comment: This.is still causing me problems is it because outside of my function I do: this.contain = undefined;  because when I put a break point in contain is still set as undefined, when it should be container, any help would be great